# how to write Cron expression with initial delay - Quartz in mule?

Tags: cron, mule, mule-studio, mule-component, cronexpression

In my mule flow, currently the cron expression in the Quartz component is **0/10 * * * * ?**  which triggers for every 10 secs. I need to modify my cron job to work with initial delay of 5 secs? How can i accommodate this by just making change to cron expression?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<inbound>
            <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="myServiceJob" startDelay="5000" repeatInterval="1000">
                <quartz:event-generator-job/>
            </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Quartz component has a Start Delay property in milliseconds

```
<quartz:inbound-endpoint  doc:name="Quartz" jobName="StartFlow" startDelay="5000" repeatInterval="0" cronExpression="0/10 * * * * ?" >
```

Comment: Thanks.. Is there any way to accommodate this by just modifying cron expression instead of configuring startDelay?

Comment: No, Cron expression doesnt have that option: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm